# client removal of .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.4

Can one, without server root access, delete a previously uploaded .htaccess file?  The server can be accessed from the command line (e.g., ftp.[url] and permissions) but the file listing displays .htaccess_bak, not the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with permission to write to a directory can delete any file in it (except when the sticky bit is set, e.g. on `/tmp`), even if it is owned by someone else.

Thus, a user can always delete files in their home directory, as they own it and it is writable by them. Similarly they can delete files in other directories provided they have write access to those directories.